# Can UnetStack run offline?

Tags: python, offline, unetstack

Is it possible to access UnetStack through the Python API without an internet connection, while still being able to perform other functionalities?

I would like to build an offline underwater acoustic communication system using the Unetstack framework.

Comment: Yes, The UnetStack framework allows for offline use, so you can build your underwater acoustic communication system using the UnetStack framework and interact with it using Python APIs without requiring an internet connection.

Comment: When using the Python API to call Unetstack, it requires an IP address.'''# Connect to the Unet audio SDOAM
sock = UnetSocket('196.168.100.159', 1100)
gw = sock.getGateway()''' How can I solve the issue of the IP address if there is no network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comments:

If you’re working in an offline environment without access to network connections, you can still communicate with UnetStack using the Python API by simulating the network locally. One approach is to set up a local loopback interface and use a local IP address, such as 127.0.0.1, to connect to UnetStack.

Here’s an example:

```
from unetpy import UnetSocket

# Use localhost IP address for local communication
sock = UnetSocket('127.0.0.1', 1100)
gw = sock.getGateway()
# Proceed with your communication with UnetStack
```

This way, you can interact with UnetStack using the Python API without the need for an external network connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this issue !

Comment: Is your doubts cleared?

Comment: Yeah!  I will try the method you provided.